# Separate Desktop and Mobile sites - How do i plan the backend?

Tags: javascript, php, .htaccess, subdomain, e-commerce

Not sure under which category my question falls. I'm in great confusion and really need some expert suggestions.

I have PHP site for E-commerce (Opencart) running on the domain- `www.example.com` and developed a PWA mobile website which is ready to be launched, at this point I have fallen into so many confusion.

- I want to host a mobile site with subdomain `m.example.com`. The backend (REST API) is same for desktop and the mobile site which is hosted in `example.com`
- when I make API calls from `m.example.com` to `example.com` preflight OPTION request is sent  for each and every request which almost takes 200ms to 300ms.
- There is an option to avoid OPTION requests by making the simple request, but not possible with my case as I have Token based authentication and need to token in every API call
- To avoid OPTION requests, the option is to host the same REST API in m.example.com as well (just checked mobile.twitter.com API request goes to mobile.twitter.com), and both `m.exampole.com` and `example.com` sharing common Database.
- This has another problem, any change in the API needs the update in both sites.

My questions are

- What is the optimal way of handling this situation?
- if I'm going with `m.example.com` - the redirection can be done at front-end level or via a .htaccess rule, which option is ideal?
- Is it a good idea to host REST API in `m.example.com` as well?

Comment: Please, for the love of any future developers looking at this codebase, do not create 2 versions of the site. Use some responsive css and then you only need to maintain one version of the site. If however; you insist on creating 2 versions of the site; there is no way to prevent the OPTIONS request because that's the browser reaching out the get the `Access-Control-Allowed-Origin` headers to see if it's allowed to interact with that server. Update your `Access-Control-Allowed-Origin` to contain all the domains that will access that service. welcome to the world of CORS, prepare to cry.

Comment: Just one instance of the service with the correct headers set will address your problems, all API calls can go to www.example.com even from m.example.com.

Comment: I have enabled CORS already. I have checked some of mobile sites for example mobile.twitter.com , m.snapdal.com, m.licious.in etc , they all make API to same subdomain instead of main domain . Just curios to know how do they do it? By hosting  API is subdomain as well ??? @AdamH

Comment: It's all in the [Access-Control-Allow-Origin Header](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Access-Control-Allow-Origin) that your web service returns. If you are using credentials then you can't use `*` for the header, instead set it to `Request.Origin` or whatever the equivalent is in PhP